# What to install with Qt Creator?

Tags: windows, mingw, qt, gdb

I'm trying to install Qt creator on Windows but it has so many options (and the whole installation requires many GB) that I really don't know which ones I need.

I only want to be able to create and debug both, command line and GUI applications, in C++. But there are all of these to choose from (and the only one that comes pre-selected is inside the "tools" sub-menu):

[image: menu 1]

If I expand one of the Qt options then I have:

[image: menu 2]

I'm sure I have to select MinGW somewhere (as that's the compiler I want). But I'm not sure if I should pick one inside the "Qt 5.11.1" sub-menu or one inside the "tools" sub-menu. Also, I'm not sure what to check to get the GDB debugger (which is the one I want). And I don't see anything related to Qt C++ to create GUI projects...

Any guidance here will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need stuff from the latest *Qt 5.11.1* branch,
and within it only the item corresponding to your compiler(s)
(but with the exact same compiler version that you are using).

The MinGW versions under Tools are older versions, to choose if that's the version
of your compiler.

Adding Sources will help tracing bugs into the Qt code, which unfortunately
is sometimes necessary.
The other items are to be checked only if you plan to use these components.

If you make mistakes, don't hesitate to uninstall and install again,
even though this may take a long time.

Comment: Thanks. So from the Qt 5.11.1 branch I should only check MingGW and Sources, and that's it? (also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say it should be the same compiler version I am using, as I'm just installing this on a new computer and have no compilers or anything yet).

Comment: If your installed MinGW version is 5.3.0 32-bit, then you install the interface under Qt 5.11.1 with that same version number. Don't install a MinGW version that isn't supported, and install it before installing Qt.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know I had to install MinGW before Qt.